# Tornado and tornado.iostream.PipeIOStream

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I need to have an asynchronously interactive log manipulation (read when something happens and write) via 2eb socket of some files in the server, but first I want to understand how to interactively and asynchronously read and write the file.

I'm still on the "reading" part.

If I execute the following piece of code and in the meanwhile I open a console and write via

```
echo foo > file.txt
```

I'm expecting something happen in the tornado console. But.. nothing. Some advice? The documentation does not contains any kind of example about tornado.iostream.PipeIOStream (or I didn't find them)

```
import os

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

clientpath = '../client'
port = 8888


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")


def tail(data):
    print "> ", data, " ."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    settings = {
        "template_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), clientpath)
    }

    handlers = [
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ]

    fd = open("file.txt")
    stream = tornado.iostream.PipeIOStream(fd.fileno())
    stream.read_until('\n', tail)

    application = tornado.web.Application(handlers, **settings)
    application.listen(port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying system calls (select, epoll, etc) don't really support regular files, so PipeIOStream doesn't either. They're close enough that it will sometimes look like it's working, but you can't actually get notified when a file has changed and there are different behaviors around end-of-file. You should use pipes or sockets for inter-process communication, not regular files.

To mimic the behavior of `tail -f`, use `add_timeout` or `PeriodicCallback` to stat the file periodically and read from it whenever the size changes (that's all `tail -f` did on most systems until relatively recently). You can also use inotify to more efficiently discover when the file changes, although integrating inotify with Tornado is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I was thinking that avoiding PeriodicCallback is a better way.. so what about instead of a normal file use some external devices? Normally if I write `open('/dev/tty..')` I get a good results.. could it work with PipeIOStream?

Comment: I haven't done it much myself but I think PipeIOStream works with TTY devices.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware this question is rather old, but the library [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) was made exactly to be able to do disk reads asynchronously, and presumably can be made to work nicely with the tornado event-loop.